# Is it best practise to give the top level App component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react/redux and am wondering how to architecture my first app. It will have a `currentUser` along with other bits of App level state.

Would it be wise to `connect()` my `App` component and pass this information down or just directly connect the components that need access to this information (e.g NavBar)?

Comment: That is a common pattern. People often opt to create “containers” – smart components that are connected to the store – and then pass data down via `props` and `context`. Not sure if there is a universal best practice and that seems like it would be a highly opinionated question in the community. Maybe check out `react-boilerplate` for an example of what the community is generally doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Redux FAQ entry at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components :

> Early Redux documentation advised that you should only have a few connected components near the top of your component tree. However, time and experience has shown that that generally requires a few components to know too much about the data requirements of all their descendants, and forces them to pass down a confusing number of props.
>
> The current suggested best practice is to categorize your components as “presentational” or “container” components, and extract a connected container component wherever it makes sense:
>
> Emphasizing “one container component at the top” in Redux examples was a mistake. Don't take this as a maxim. Try to keep your presentation components separate. Create container components by connecting them when it's convenient. Whenever you feel like you're duplicating code in parent components to provide data for same kinds of children, time to extract a container. Generally as soon as you feel a parent knows too much about “personal” data or actions of its children, time to extract a container.
>
> In general, try to find a balance between understandable data flow and areas of responsibility with your components.